# Como subir varios archivos con distintos inputs?

Tags: php, mysqli

Deseo que se pueda elegir solo un archivo por cada input y se suban todos y aparte que se inserten ciertos datos, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $folders    = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `folders` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    $tfolders   = $folders->num_rows;

    $users      = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` ASC");

    if (isset($_POST['sfile'])) {
        while($row=$folders->fetch_array()) { 
                $target_dir     = "files/".$_SESSION['zona']."/";
                $extension      = '.' . pathinfo($_FILES[$row['id']]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$row['id']]["tmp_name"], "files/". $_SESSION['zona'] . "/" . $row['name'] . $extension)) {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `upfiles` (`name`, `extension`, `folderid`, `zona`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") or trigger_error($conn->error);
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $name, $extension, $folderid, $zona);

                    $name       = $row['name'];
                    $folderid   = $row['id'];
                    $zona       = $_SESSION['zona'];

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                $func->redirect('index.php');
        }   
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
<main style="text-align: center;">
<?php
    echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

    while($row=$folders->fetch_array())
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo "<input type='file' name='".$id."' id='selectedFile".$id."' style='display: none;' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='fid".$id."' value='".$id."'/>";
        echo '<div id="button'.rand(1,10).'" class="boton" onclick="document.getElementById(\'selectedFile'.$id.'\').click();">'.$name.'</div>';
    }
    echo "<br><button type='submit' name='sfile'>Enviar archivos</button></form>";
?>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

El problema aca es que si selecciono todos los archivos en cada uno de los inputs solo se sube el primero, algunas ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en que envias varios archivos como si fuesen 1. Cuando lo que envias es un arreglo de distintos archivos.

Lo que debes hacer es enviar un arreglo de archivos para poder obtener 1 a 1.

```
<input name="imagenes[]" type="file" /><br />

<input name="imagenes[]" type="file" /><br />
```

En php

```
$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file_post['name']);
$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
```

[verifica esta informacion de php](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php)